# Why does KMZ to GPX reverse the objectid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, gpx, kmz, data-interoperability

I am working on KMZ to GPX conversion and every time I use the data interoperability extension and quick export it seems to reverse the objectid, now my 1st waypoint is the last placemark point of the KMZ file that was used to convert it.

I am using ArcGIS desktop advanced license 10.2.2.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: Not an answer as such - a note I've had similar issues with conversion with other tools. At the heart of the issue seems to be that most GIS formats (including KML) are designed for recording 'things' in a wide sense. GPX is targeted at recording or planning a journey. It seems difficult to find ways to tell most GIS software the additional details required to construct a really good GPX file. Really we want to be able to tell the GIS system where the start/end of a GPX should be, what order features have, where there's a break, and how to join multiple lines/points in a specific order.